# Angular Controller As Webpack

Tags: angularjs, webpack

Using Webpack to build an Angular project. I've got a MainController for the site which is using the controller as syntax:

JS:

```
module.exports = angular.module('app').controller('MainController', MainController);

function MainController() {
   let vm = this;

   vm.something = 'Something';
}
```

HTML:

```
<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="MainController as vm">
   <h1>{{vm.something}}</h1> <!-- Outputs Nothing -->
</body>
```

Trying to bind vm.something results in nothing. However if I inject $scope into the controller and change vm to $scope `something` (without vm) binds with no problem.

Example:

JS:

```
module.exports = angular.module('app').controller('MainController', MainController);

function MainController($scope) {

   $scope.something = 'Something';
}
```

HTML:

```
<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="MainController as vm"><!-- Not Changed -->
   <h1>{{something}}</h1> <!-- Outputs Correctly -->
</body>
```

Any one ran into a problem like this? I've search high and low and can't seem to find a reason why Controller as wouldn't work but came up empty. The only thing I can figure is that Webpack's compiling is throwing something off, but really that doesn't make any sense.

Webpack.config:

```
var webpack = require('webpack');

var commonsPlugin = new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin('common.js');

module.exports = {
        entry: {
            app : "./src/app/app.js",
        },
        output: {
            path: "app/scripts/",
            filename: "[name].js",
        },
        module: {
            loaders: [
                { test: /\.js$/, loader: 'babel', exclude: /node_modules/},
                { test: /\.html$/, loader: 'raw', exclude: /node_modules/}
            ]
        },
        stats: {
            colors: false,
            modules: true,
            reasons: true
        },
        plugins: [commonsPlugin]
};
```

Comment: What version of angular? Controller As is not supported in earlier versions like 1.2.x. Do you see any errors in the console?

Comment: 1.3.15 - Using `Controller as` without issue in directives.

Comment: Can you replicate issue in a plnkr? console, any errors? Also `angular.module('app')` you have the `app` defined right?

Comment: Here is a working plunker. http://plnkr.co/edit/e1kV7v?p=preview

Comment: What is in your webpack.config.js?

Comment: Getting it to work isn't the problem, getting to work when complied with Webpack seems to be the tripping point.

Comment: Webpack.config added to post.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution?